# iPhone / iPod Button in background shearing through to UIAlertView TextBox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uialertview

As I type into a textbox on a UIAlertView, an ImageButton in the background starts shearing through. It only happens when the text gets close to the image.

[image: The problem]

The code for the alertview is as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"... number"
                                                message:nil
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
[alert setTag:1];
[alert setOpaque:true];
[alert show];

//EDIT
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        NSString* title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if ([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
        {
            [self doSomething1];
        }

        if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Are you sure?"] && [title isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            [self doSomething2];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1){
        NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        if( [inputText length] == 10 )
        {
            NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [def setObject:inputText
                    forKey:@"FIELD"];
            [def synchronize];
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I have tried setting it to opaque, I have tried looking for z-indexing values, and I have also tried scaling the image down to the smallest it needs to be. Taking screenshots does not help. This only happens in iOS 7.

Comment: I am using this type of alert view in my app and there is no problem in my end, are you doing any other process with the image view or any other process in back?

Comment: Hi there. No I am not. The image has been loaded via the Storyboard designer.

Comment: The image is not being accessed while the user is typing.

Comment: Have you implemented UIAlertView delegates?, and if implemented then what process you are doing in that? Because your behaviour is very strange, there is something going on in back while alert view is on screen. If possible then please add some more code for more reference.

Comment: I have edited the code to reflect the UIAlertView's delegates

Comment: I have tested your code in my iOS7 device but i'm not getting any problem. But I think alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton is causing problem for you. Are you getting this problem in device only or in simulator also?

Comment: A standalone example project demonstrating the issue might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAlertView are not shown in the same UIWindow as the rest of your view controllers. They are shown in their own UIWindow with a windowLevel of `UIWindowLevelAlert`. This other window is transparent (mostly) and renders on top of your main window. This makes UIAlertView objects not interact as well with other views you may have on screen. Do not modify any properties from the underlying UIView class.

The code you show above has `if (alertView.tag == 1)` as well as `if (alertView.tag == 2)`, but it only ever creates a UIAlertView with a tag value of 1. Is there somewhere else you are creating a second alert? Are you possibly showing a second alert before the first one completes its disappearance animation? That has been known to cause graphical tears.

The delegate method `-alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` can be called from within the `-drawRect:` method of the UIAlertView. The draw method must be extremely fast to avoid causing graphical tearing. Yours calls `NSUserDefaults -synchronize`, which performs a disk write operation. You should not perform any operation within your `-alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` method, besides determining the response value. If you want to be notified of changes to the text field, assign yourself as the UITextFieldDelegate and implement `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. That method should be safe to call `NSUserDefaults -synchronize` from.

As an additional tip, you could make your code much easier to manage using the [PSPDFAlertView](https://github.com/steipete/PSAlertView).